# Jetpack Compose HorizontalPager offer by current page

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, horizontal-pager

I wanna implement this design: I have 2 pages, the second page's left side part visible on the first page, and the first page's right side on the second.

I played with `contentPadding`, `pageSpacing`, `modifier.graphicsLayer` and so on, but nothing worked. What is the correct setup? Thank you

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of custom [`PageSize`](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/8e53097add74f65f879ac43d64e0d40ffb73ad94:compose/foundation/foundation/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/pager/Pager.kt;l=235). For example, we use this `FillPageSize`, where you can specify the fraction of available space that each page takes:

```
class FillPageSize(
    private val fraction: Float = 1F,
): PageSize {

    override fun Density.calculateMainAxisPageSize(availableSpace: Int, pageSpacing: Int): Int {
        return (availableSpace * fraction).roundToInt()
    }
}
```

Usage is simple:

```
HorizontalPager(
    pageSize = FillPageSize(.8F)
) { ... }
```

You can easily modify that to subtract specified amount of pixels from available space or something.

Comment: It's working, thank you! A "new" question: how can it wotk with 3 pages? In thi  case the middle page's left side 0,2 the first page, on the right side the 3rd page's 0.2f and the middle page in th center

Answer (score 0):

You can change `contentPadding` for this.

```
val pagerState = rememberPagerState(0) { 2 }
var contentPaddingValues by remember { mutableStateOf(PaddingValues(end = 70.dp)) }

LaunchedEffect(pagerState.currentPage) {
    contentPaddingValues = if (pagerState.currentPage == 0) PaddingValues(end = 70.dp) else PaddingValues(start = 70.dp)
}

HorizontalPager(
    state = pagerState,
    contentPadding = contentPaddingValues,
) {
    // your content
}
```

[image]

Comment: Lags for me :(
https://im4.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-4-d470f169e1.gif